# How to construct large, hereditarily separable compact spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In [1] Fedorcuk, using diamond,  proved that there is a hereditarily separable compact space of cardinality $2^{2^\omega}$.To my best knowledge, Kunen created a humanly digestible proof, but he has not published it (and he passed away). Can I find Kunen's proof somewhere? Or do you know any other proof of the theorem of Fedorcuk?

[1] Fedorčuk, V. V.
The cardinality of hereditarily separable bicompacta. (Russian)
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 222 (1975), no. 2, 302–305.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was informed that the following joint paper of Dzamoja and Kunen contains the proof I was looking for.

[Dz̆amonja, Mirna; Kunen, Kenneth Measures on compact HS spaces.
Fund. Math. 143 (1993), no. 1, 41–54](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm143/fm14314.pdf).

Comment: Istvan presented Kunen's proof during a course in Amsterdam around 1980; he had a photocopy at the time.

Comment: @KP Hart.  He had. But he could not find it. Anyway, we think that we could recover the original  argument from the Dzamonja-Kunen paper.